# decode value in xml using shell

Tags: unix, base64, decode

i am trying to decode a value from xml. please find a sample below. This will be multiple blocks. I need to find tag  and decode the contents and generate the same output. i am just in the process of starting the script.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<log-entry serial="abcde" domain="abc">
<date>Tue Oct 17 2017</date>
<time utc="abcde">14:14:30</time>
<type>all</type>
<class>ccccc</class>
<object>Web_Token</object>
<level num="5">notice</level>
<transaction>xxxxx</transaction>
<global-transaction-id>xxxxx</global-transaction-id>
<client>X.X.X.X</client>
<message>
<base64>**encodeddata**</base64>
</message>
</log-entry>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>

i need output 

<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<log-entry serial="abcde" domain="abc">
<date>Tue Oct 17 2017</date>
<time utc="abcde">14:14:30</time>
<type>all</type>
<class>ccccc</class>
<object>Web_Token</object>
<level num="5">notice</level>
<transaction>xxxxx</transaction>
<global-transaction-id>xxxxx</global-transaction-id>
<client>X.X.X.X</client>
<message>
<base64>**decodeddata**</base64>
</message>
</log-entry>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I am in the process of Iteration, started with decoding the value.

```
sed -n 's/<base64>\(.*\)<\/base64>/\1/p' log.txt | base64 --decode
```

thanks.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: don't parse xml with sed. Are you able to install xml parser?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 xmllint --xpath '//message/base64/text()' file.xml 2>/dev/null |
     base64 -d -
```